# android get NFC tag without using dispatch system

Tags: android, nfc

I want to get some help for implementing the following scenario:

the nfc tag is glued to the back of my android phone, and I want to write a program to I/O with it.

So far the only way I knew about obtaining a Tag object is through dispatch system, which requires the tag to be move close to the phone to trigger detection.

Is there a way to obtain the Tag without relying on the intent from dispatch system? So I can just put an button on the UI, and whenever its clicked it would perform I/O with the tag?

Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to get NFC tag using reader mode ? if yes , how ? any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running Android 4.4+, you can do this with almost undocumented "reader mode" feature of the NFC system. Whenever you turn on reader mode it will look for a tag in its field and pass it to your reader callback. This lets you reacquire a tag that is already in the field without physical movement by disabling and reenabling reader mode. [Enabling reader mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableReaderMode(android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle))

Comment: I was looking into that API the other day, didnt get it working. Will try it again and report back. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not the tag dispatch system which requires the tag to move close to the phone. The tag dispatch system only catch the event and send the scanned tag to the "right" application.

It's NFC why you need to be physical close to perform I/O communication. When they move close together they perform a handshake which identifies the tag. After the handshake Android sends (with e.g. the tag dispatch system) to the application.

If you had communication and the tag is released, you need to perform another handshake to reconnect with that tag. I think when you glued the tag on your phone it's not possible to reconnect to the tag without physical movement. Maybe after a certain time-out, but you can't rely on the behaviour.