# Enforce NFC dispatch event // disable and re-enable NFC system capabilities

Tags: android, nfc

**Background**

I am working on an NFC communication interface between an embedded system and an Android app.
The embedded system can react to commands written to the NDEF message of the NFC tag. During the processing of the command, the RF field is inactive. 
Usually, upon termination of the command processing, the `android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED` event is triggered and I can process the response in my app.

Unfortunately, this is not always the case, and sometimes, no such event is emitted by the Android device. If I physically remove the Android device from the NFC tag and place it on the tag again, the `NDEF_DISCOVERED` event is triggered.
I want to implement a polling mechanism that triggers the `NDEF_DISCOVERED` event.

**What I tried**

I started off with disabling and re-enabling the ReaderMode of the NFC adapter but without success:

```
    public void reconnectNfc() {
      NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = getNfcAdapter();
      nfcAdapter.disableReaderMode(this);
      getNfcAdapter().enableReaderMode(...);     
    }
```

the dispatch event is not triggered by disabling the reader mode.

The accepted answer to this question:
[android get NFC tag without using dispatch system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246936/android-get-nfc-tag-without-using-dispatch-system?rq=1)
suggests that I could get an updated `Tag` object to dispatch this way, but unfortunately it is not working for me.

Is there a way to turn the NFC system capabilities off and on again?

**Interaction system**

In my AndroidManifest.xml I specified an activity that is started when the Android system receives an NFC dispatch intent:

```
    <activity
        android:name="myNfcDispatchActivity"
        ...>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The dispatching in the `myNfcDispatchActivity` performed like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    getNfcAdapter().enableReaderMode(this, 
        tag -> {
          Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
          mainHandler.post(() -> dispatchTag(tag));
        },
        NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS | NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A,
        null);
}
```

and I process the NDEF message of the `tag` object in the `dispatchTag()` method

Comment: You seems to be mixing up 2 different methods of interacting with NFC cards in Android ``android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED` is from the `Intent` system and `enableReaderMode` is from the newer callback system. Provide more code on how you are interacting via NFC

Comment: Putting that `intent-filter` in your Manifest will only cause the NFC service to Start your App if not already running when a Card with an NDEF message is discovered which you would then need to process, you would need to `enableForegroudDispatch` to receive Intents to an already running App. You really need to show the whole of `myNfcDispatchActivity`

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot show the whole myNfcDispatchActivity (it is quite big anyways) but I hope that the added snippet helps to clarify my problem.

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer of this question: 
[How can I reconnect to IsoDep tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233264/how-can-i-reconnect-to-isodep-tag)
suggests that there is no way to solve my problem programatically

> All you can do in this case is to physically remove the tag and present it to the reader again.